# MBCircularProgressBarView not animated in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
 //MARK: - TableView Delegate
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
        withIdentifier: "ListOfTaskTableViewCell",
        for: indexPath) as! ListOfTaskTableViewCell

    //Configuare notification cell
    print(self.listItems.count)
    cell.lblName?.text = self.listItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblPersentage?.text = self.listPersentage [indexPath.row]
    cell.imgPersentageIcon?.image = UIImage(named: self.listIcons[indexPath.row])
    //Set as comment

    if self.floatPercentage[indexPath.row] >= 50.0 {
        cell.redProgressBar.isHidden = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, animations: {
            cell.greenProgressBar.value = CGFloat(self.floatPercentage[indexPath.row])
            }, completion: nil)

    }
    else{
        cell.greenProgressBar.isHidden = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, animations: {
            cell.redProgressBar.value = CGFloat(self.floatPercentage[indexPath.row])
            }, completion: nil)

    }                

    return cell
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try This in **WillDisplayCell**

```
if self.floatPercentage[indexPath.row] >= 50.0 {
    cell.redProgressBar.isHidden = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, animations: {
        cell.greenProgressBar.value = CGFloat(self.floatPercentage[indexPath.row])
        }, completion: nil)

}
else{
    cell.greenProgressBar.isHidden = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, animations: {
        cell.redProgressBar.value = CGFloat(self.floatPercentage[indexPath.row])
        }, completion: nil)

}
```